# How can I filter a wordlist to only include words of a certain minimum size?

Tags: linux, word-list

I'd like to have a file/list of all passwords in `rockyou.txt` that are greater than or equal to 10 characters. I'd imagine there's some one-liner like `cat rockyou.txt | grep (length >= 10) > output.txt` but I can't get the right syntax

Comment: have you seen: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1193526/how-do-i-get-words-of-certain-length

Comment: that link also includes boundaries for both min/max length at the same time, extra helpful. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to filter all words, which contain N or more characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585255/how-to-filter-all-words-which-contain-n-or-more-characters)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk 'length($0) >= 10' rockyou.txt
```

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
grep -P '^.{10,}' rockyou.txt
```

or

```
grep '^.\{10,\}' rockyou.txt
```

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -lne 'print if length() >= 10' rockyou.txt
```

Comment: the awk solution was great thanks, and for completeness/anyone coming here from google: its `awk <filter> <inputfile>` if you'd like to create a new file `awk <filter> <inputfile> > <outputfile>` for example `awk 'length($0) >= 10' rockyou.txt > rockyou_over10chars.txt`

Comment: Add `-l` to the perl options; otherwise it's counting newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo grep -x '.\{10,X\}' rockyou.txt > NEWrockyou.txt
```

where `X` is the maximum length you want (put a large number to get them all).